# Peut-on utiliser l'expression « Calculer la force nette » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, physique

J'enseigne la physique à l'université. J'ai donné un sujet d'examen qui comportait une question comme celle-ci :

> Quelle est **la force nette** qui agit sur le point matériel...?

Je n'ai pas précisé car j'ai pensé que le sens est entendu ; à savoir la somme des forces; la force totale;  la force résultante, en suivant (par exemple) la terminologie [ici](https://fr.wikihow.com/calculer-la-force-nette) et [ici](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=net%20force). Cependant, quasiment tous les étudiants ont échoué à comprendre la signification.

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi. Est-ce une expression "franglaise" et inconnue ?
Faut-il éviter un tel emploi de l'adjectif net ?
(En fait, Larousse [en ligne](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/net/54328?q=net#53966)  ne donne pas un seul exemple dans ce contexte.)

Comment: Non, **force nette** est tout à fait correct. Est-il possible que les étudiants n'aient jamais reçu la définition? Je n'ai pas fait d'études de physique, mais même sans me rappeler de mes cours, je suis capable de comprendre que "force nette" représente la résultante des forces après interférences entre elles.

Comment: Merci. Dans le cours j'ai employé plutôt d'autres expressions. Cependant. il faut que j'avoue que j'attendais que la terminologie était déjà acquise dans le secondaire (terminal. collège etc). Évidement ce n'est pas le cas:-)!

Comment: Je viens du Canada, où l'anglais est peut-être plus présent qu'en France. On nous apprenait bien «force résultante» à l'école, mais on nous mentionnait aussi régulièrement «force nette», que l'on disait omniprésente, quoique l'on gardât ses distances avec elle. Peut-être un peu une sorte de standard non-officiel auquel on jugeait bon de nous exposer.

Comment: Il vaut mieux faire des recherches sous le vocable "physique" ou "mécanique newtoniene". C'est partout dans la mécanique newtonienne dans les sites libellés: site.fr

Comment: Il te suffit de regarder les programmes du second cycle pour savoir quel est le terme utilisé dans les programmes. Si ce n'est pas le terme des programmes il est normal qu'il ne soit pas connu et c'est à toi de leur enseigner le terme. Ce n'est pas sur FL qu'il faut poser la question mais à tes collègues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bien que l'expression soit correcte et compréhensible, l'adjectif **net** est souvent utilisé par opposition à **brut**: par exemple salaire net / salaire brut.

Dans les souvenirs de mes cours universitaires de mécanique, il me semble qu'on utilisait plutôt **somme des forces** ou **force résultante**, rarement **force nette** (voir par exemple [ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_r%C3%A9sultante)).

Je peux donc comprendre la perplexité d'étudiants habitués à la terminologie **force résultante** se demandant pourquoi le sujet fait référence à une **force nette** plutôt qu'une **somme des forces** (sachant justement que les termes employés en sciences ne sont jamais anodins) et tenter de comprendre le concept de **force nette** à partir de ce que serait une hypothétique **force brute**.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse exhaustive.  L'expression "force nette" existe également dans l'ouvrage "Thermodynamique : Une approche pragmatique". (Traduction et adaptation française d'un ouvrage américain par Yunus Çengel et Micheal Boles.) Je suis d'accord avec vous que l'adjectif net est utilisé signifiant pur. C'était ma faute que je l'ai considérée comme entendue la signification total (celle de mécanique). Je détiens le niveau C1 de la langue française mais évidement je ne suis pas entièrement francophone:-)!

Answer (score 5):

À mon sens il serait plus juste de parler de [force résultante](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_r%C3%A9sultante).

Pour autant que je m'en souvienne, et mes cours de physique sont vraiment très lointains (les années 70), les professeurs utilisaient tous le terme « force résultante », je ne me souviens pas avoir entendu « force nette. »

Comment: Oui, j'en sais et évidement j'emploie cette terminologie. Mais, pourquoi quand même ? Pourriez-vous m'expliquer ? Le lien https://fr.wikihow.com/calculer-la-force-nette concerne le secondaire. Moi, je m'adresse aux étudiants de licence. Le terme devrait être connue, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @dimitris: voir ma mise à jour.

Comment: Merci vivement de nouveau. Bien que le terme existe dans un ouvrage (adaptation française d'un ouvrage américain) la prochaine fois j'essayerai d'utiliser de la terminologie classique (ou bien je poserai tout d'abord des questions à ce forum:-)!).

Answer (score 1):

Le terme "**force nette**" est tout à fait correct en français.

Ce n'est pas un anglicisme, mais ce n'est pas non plus un terme couramment utilisé dans le langage: c'est un terme utilisé en physique. Le terme devrait avoir été expliqué dans le cours. Si cela n'a pas été fait, il est tout à fait possible que les élèves ne l'ait jamais entendu. Si cela a été fait, peut-être n'ont-ils simplement pas révisé :D

Comment: Merci vivement pour la réponse. Dans le cours j'ai employé plutôt des autres expressions. Vu les liens que j'ai inclus je pensais que la terminologie était déjà acquise dans l'école (terminal. collège etc). C'était donc ma faute. J'avais dû leur expliqué et précisé l'emploi et contacter initialement  french.stackexchange.com :-)!

Comment: @dimitris Pas de problème! Par contre, pour moi, c'est un terme de seconde/première/terminale (si vous êtes dans le système français). Si vous enseignez dans le supérieur, je pense qu'il est tout à fait acceptable de considérer la notion comme sue. De plus (toujours un avis personnel), je pense qu'un étudiant dans le supérieur est capable de déduire la notion de par son nom.

Comment: Oui, j'ai enseigne à une université française (licence). Moi aussi, je pensais que la terminologie a été déjà acquise durant le parcours précédant. Par souci d'exhaustivité, l'énoncé complète était comme ci-après :   " Quelle la force nette qui agit sur une voiture se déplaçant à une vitesse constante de
70 km/h : a) si elle roule sur une chaussée de niveau ? b) si elle monte une pente ?"

Comment: J'avais déjà montré cela avec des textes de lycée. Il me semble que votre réponse aurait pu s'exprimer dans un commentaire....

Comment: @Lambie Hum, j'ai posté cette réponse il y a près de 4 ans, je ne vois pas comment j'aurais pu poster un commentaire sur la vôtre, qui date de trois semaines '-' Je pense que Dimitris a eu sa réponse depuis :p

Comment: Désolée. Je viens de m'en rendre compte.

Answer (score 1):

> Deuxième loi de Newton    Lex II: Mutationem motus proportionalem esse
> vi motrici impressae, et fieri secundum lineam rectam qua vis illa
> imprimitur.
>
> L'accélération accent(a;->) d'un corps est parallèle et directement
> proportionelle à la **force nette** appliquée accent(F;->) sur le
> corps, elle est dans la même direction que la force nette, et elle est
> inversement proportionnelle à la masse m du corps, soit
> accent(F;->)=m*accent(a;->).

[force_gravitation_masse](https://media4.obspm.fr/public/ressources_lu/pages_forces/force-gravitation-masse-excercices-1.html)

Et encore:

> La deuxième loi révolutionne la physique en établissant une relation
> mathématique entre la force nette appliquée et la dérivée de  (et
> non entre la **force nette** et la quantité de mouvement elle-même,
> comme on le pensait depuis Aristote).

[force nette](https://www.editions-ellipses.fr/PDF/9782340047594_extrait.pdf)

> Première loi du mouvement o La première loi du mouvement de Newton
> décrit ce qu’il se passe quand **la force nette** sur un objet est
> nulle : toutes les forces individuelles s’annulent et il n’y a pas de
> changement dans le mouvement Si  =  alors pas de
> changement dans le mouvement

[Introduction à l'animation physique](https://perso.liris.cnrs.fr/nicolas.pronost/UCBL/M1IF37/M1IF37-IntroductionAnimPhysique.pdf)

[Pas tous les signes sont bien reproduits. Par contre, on voit bien que **force nette** est utilisé pour expliquer deux  lois de Newton en français. Je connais pas grande chose en physique.]