# Emploi de "chaussée de niveau"

Tags: traduction, anglais, science, canada

> What is the net force acting on a car cruising at a
>   constant velocity of 70 km/h (a) on a level road and (b) on
>   an uphill road?
>
> Quelle est la force nette qui agit sur une voiture se déplaçant à une vitesse constante
>   de 70 km/h : a) si elle roule sur une chaussée de niveau ? b) si elle monte une pente ?

La première phrase vient d'un ouvrage de Thermodynamique [américain](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073398179); la seconde vient de la [traduction](https://www.amazon.fr/Thermodynamique-approche-pragmatique-Yunus-Cengel/dp/2804187292/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1548092721&sr=1-3&keywords=Y.%20A.%20Cengel) en français de cet ouvrage par quelques scientifiques du Québec et de Montréal.

[Ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28861/peut-on-utiliser-lexpression-calculer-la-force-nette) l'ambivalence de *force nette* a été abordée. Cependant, un collègue, locuteur natif du français (venant de France), m'a dit qu'il vaut mieux utiliser *route plane* au lieu de *chaussée de niveau* mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi *chaussée de niveau* n'est pas préférable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Cependant, un collègue français m'a dit qu'il vaut mieux utiliser route plane au lieu de chaussée de niveau mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi chaussée de niveau n'est pas préférable.

Je suis d'accord avec lui pour recommander d'éviter *chaussée de niveau* car c'est une expression qui n'est pas idiomatique. Je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un dire *chaussée de niveau* en France, ou alors, pour parler d'une chaussée qui est au même niveau qu'autre chose, ou avec un décalage constant avec cet autre chose, par exemple le trottoir. *Route de niveau* ne serait pas plus recommandable ni facilement compréhensible.

En revanche, bien que parler d'une *route plane* puisse être considéré comme légèrement ambigu sachant qu'on peut arguer qu'une route en pente peut très bien aussi être plane, le fait que la question suivante l'oppose à *route en pente* rend manifeste qu'il faut sous-entendre *route plane horizontale*.

Answer (score 2):

La définition du [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/niveau/54687/locution) donne une définition explicite de « de niveau » qui correspond exactement au problème.

> De niveau, sur le 
>   même plan horizontal : Terrasse qui est de 
>   niveau avec le sol.


  Il est donc légitime de se demander pourquoi ne pas utiliser cette expression adjectivale.

Ils vous le déconseillent probablement parce que, comme je le suppose, ils sont mathématiciens, et ils auraient dans l'idée d'éviter toute assimilation à « de niveau » tel qu'employé dans la définition de certaines courbes dans les graphes de fonctions de deux variables, lesquelles on appelle « courbes de niveau », ce qui a bien quelque chose à voir avec un plan « plat, à l' horizontale ». Je ne vois pas d'autre raison et ne trouve pas celle-ci très justifiées (touts les routes « planes » suivent après tout une courbe de niveau).

Cependant, en vous conseillant « plane » je pense que vos collègues ne feraient pas la meilleure des choses ; cet adjectif est sujet à une ambigüité ; on la comprend à partir de la définition du [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=3191962500;r=1;nat=;sol=0;) ;

> A. [En parlant d'une surface] **Uni, plat, sans inégalités de niveau, sans courbure**. M. Darwin considère un écran plan percé d'une ouverture sur laquelle on a placé un film très mince d'une substance homogène dont les atomes ont une masse M (L. DE BROGLIE, Bases interprét. mécan. ondul., 1963, p.77).
>  
>   P. exagér. **Qui est horizontal**.

À mon avis « une route horizontale » serait peut être un meilleur choix que « plane ».

Answer (score 1):

En complément, au [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=LEVEL%20ROAD%20TEST&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) on a *essai en palier* et *essai sur route plane* pour *level road test*. Je pense que le terme *level* pose un problème d'analyse et l'idée des *levels* (paliers, niveaux) interfère avec la notion ou s'avère peut-être possible en langue anglaise dans ce contexte. On voudrait voir *flat*, mais pour [certains](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/flat-vs-level-street-road.2599204/) ça pourrait signifier *sans imperfection*. Au [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19058269) on a *route en palier* pour *level road*, assurément quelque chose de différent que plane et unique. *À niveau* peut traduire *flush* (*level with*) mais sans complément (*à niveau avec* quoi? ) je le trouve indéterminé alors qu'avec un adverbe j'aurais personnellement mieux compris (chaussée *parfaitement à niveau*). On pense que l'emploi de *de niveau* dans a) est sur-spécialisé alors que b) est plus usuel, alors qu'en anglais on a *road* dans les deux cas (et un verbe unique) avec simplement l'adjectif qui varie. On n'est pas très friand de cette traduction-là.